# Backbone.BabySitter inner parameter - Javascript Scope

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, marionette

I'm using the great [Backbone.BabySitter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter) with my Marionette project, and have a function like this in the example:

```
container.children.each(function(view){
      // process each view individually, here
});
```

Is there a way to reach 'view' without declaring a function in the loop? I'm trying to make my code JSLint compliant, and I can't figure out if there's a solution to this.

**EDIT:**

This probably most likely due to the fact that this each function is in a loop itself:

Right now I am doing this:

```
 var that = this,
     otherParameter = array[i],
     i;

 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {


    container.children.each(function(view){
         that.backboneFunction(view, otherParameter);
    });

 };
```

What I want to do is somehow get that function out of the each loop, as I think that's why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Doesn't `this` evaluate to the view instance?

Comment: What exactly is JSLint saying is wrong with that?

Comment: @muistooshort it's 'declaring a function in a loop'

Comment: @DavidSulc - good point -- I'm trying to work with that now!

Comment: @DavidSulc - it doesn't seem to be. If I call my function and pass 'this' as a parameter -- so containter.each(myFunction(this)); -- it doesn't pass the correct parameter :(

Comment: Are you certain that it is complaining about that? I can't believe that any sane tool would complain about such a common idiom, I even checked on jslint.com and it said nothing about that. Perhaps you need to supply more context than just that `each` call.

Comment: @muistooshort I will post more context - this is the error I'm getting http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/

Comment: @muistooshort I've added more context. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @muistooshort you're right -- it's due to the fact that this each function is occurring in a loop. I've updated the code with more scope.

Comment: It is probably trying to keep you from making the usual "closure within a loop" mistake where all the callback functions end up with the `i = array.length`. Of course, that doesn't apply in this but JSLint is a whiny little so-and-so that complains anyway. Try defining the function outside the loop, I don't know what sort of contortions you'll need to make JSLint shut up though. Thanks for reminding why I stay far away JSLint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as was helpfully pointed out @muistooshort, the issue was not with the each, but with the loop the each was in.

To fix this, I declared the function properly outside of the entire loop, and called it at the right place.

Though I do wish JSLint had an option to turn this off!